# How to check if user clicks no on NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, swift, ios-permissions

When user is on `MainViewController`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
}
```

`viewDidLoad()` will run and the alert will appear

[image]

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Accessing user location to determine the nearest pickup location</string>
        <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Accessing user location to determine the nearest pickup location</string>
```

The main question is, if user clicks Don't allow, how do I check programmtically? for example

```
// Example code snippet, not from apple officials
if NSlocation is nil then I want to do some alert
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager

Answer (score 3):

If the user chooses to deny your app access to location services, `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` will be `.denied` (though you should also watch out for `.restricted`. If you'd like to be notified when the user chooses whether or not to allow or deny your app, you can make yourself your location manager's `delegate` and implement the proper method:

```
class MainViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() -> Void{
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) -> Void{
        switch status{
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                // You're allowed to use location services
            case .denied, .restricted:
                // You can't use location services
            default:
                // This case shouldn't be hit, but is necessary to prevent a compiler error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just one more question if you don't mind, how do I direct the user to the settings of the app so that the user could toggle the location

Answer (score 0):

Use below delegate method of `CLLocationManager` to check user click on **Don't allow** button in permission alert.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status {
        case .denied:
           print("Show you own alert here")
            break
        }
    }
```

To redirect user in location settings follow below:

1. Add URL Types "prefs" like below image
   [image]
2. Write this code on button action:

   ```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")!)
   ```